# How can I listen to accelerometer in the background with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, accelerometer

I am new to mobile development and is trying to develop an app that can listen to accelerometer events even if the app is not in the foreground.

I am using the [sensors](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors) plugin to listen to accelerometer and trigger a notification and report to server if the application detects that the phone fell. Once I toggle the screen off, the app stops triggering notifications and reporting fall detection.

Any ideas how I can implement this?

Comment: Hi Tin, Try to add the relevant code snippet in the question to get better help.

Comment: Hi @NadeemIqbal, I havent started coding to make it run in the background since I am still researching how to implement it thus can't put in any code yet :(